# Paused dag restarted on upgrading airflow from 1.8.0 to 1.8.1?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Recently i upgraded airflow from 1.8.0 to 1.8.1. The upgrade went fine but once i restarted the web server and scheduler, all paused dags restarted automatically and started running multiple runs from the date they have been stopped. It messed up most of user data and we need to clean up manually. How can we prevent this happening in the future upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

In `airflow.cfg` just make sure to have `dags_are_paused_at_creation = True` and I believe that should take care of your issue. It is super annoying to run into things like that so I'm sorry about that!